# Overriding the items in the json while using ng repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs and i have a nested json. I need to access the sub arrays and fetch the data and print them in panels. The json response is dynamic and vary. As of now i have hardcoded the json .

I have used a custom directive for forming dynamic panels. As the array grows, so does the panels.

I have to fetch the data in the sub array. The problem is, I am not able to fetch both the arrays in my sublist. If there are more than one scenario_sub in a sub_list, the last is alone getting printed. I want both of them to get printed.

Is there any way of solving this ?

Comment: In HTML5 PR, section 8.1.2.3 [Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0) explicitly says: “There must never be two or more attributes on the same start tag whose names are an ASCII case-insensitive match for each other.”

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with your JSON that you are giving, Sub_list is although and array but is enclosed inside the single object in that array. Moreover, your JSON has multiple mistakes. Here is the valid JSON that you can refer,

```
$scope.itemsList = [
        {
            Scenario_id: '1',
            Scenario_desc: 'Invoice Not Found',
            Scenario_overall_status: 'Positive',
            sub_list: [
                {
                    Scenario_sub: {
                        sub_result_id: 'a',
                        sub_result_msg: 'Invoice #6787898989 was already finalized',
                        sub_result_status: '9'
                    }
                },
                {
                    Scenario_sub: {
                        sub_result_id: 'b',
                        sub_result_msg: 'BP004 is IDLE',
                        sub_result_status: '0'
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            Scenario_id: '2',
            Scenario_desc: 'Invoice is in scheduled status.',
            Scenario_overall_status: 'Positive',
            sub_list: [
                {
                    Scenario_sub: {
                        sub_result_id: 'a',
                        sub_result_msg: 'Invoice #6787898989 was already finalized',
                        sub_result_status: '9'
                    }
                },
                {
                    Scenario_sub: {
                        sub_result_id: 'b',
                        sub_result_msg: 'BP004 is IDLE',
                        sub_result_status: '0'
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            Scenario_id: '3',
            Scenario_desc: 'Invoice is in scheduled status.',
            Scenario_overall_status: 'Positive',
            sub_list: [
                {
                    Scenario_sub: {
                        sub_result_id: 'a',
                        sub_result_msg: 'Invoice #6787898989 was already finalized',
                        sub_result_status: '9'
                    }
                },
                {
                    Scenario_sub: {
                        sub_result_id: 'b',
                        sub_result_msg: 'BP004 is IDLE',
                        sub_result_status: '0'
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            Scenario_id: '4',
            Scenario_desc: 'Invoice is not found in smart',
            Scenario_overall_status: 'Negative',
            sub_list: [
                {
                    Scenario_sub: {
                        sub_result_id: 'a',
                        sub_result_msg: 'Invoice #6787898989 was already finalized',
                        sub_result_status: '9'
                    }
                },
                {
                    Scenario_sub: {
                        sub_result_id: 'b',
                        sub_result_msg: 'BP004 is IDLE',
                        sub_result_status: '0'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
}
```

Moreover, try to keep your code much readable by having the nesting clearly displayed.

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in itemsList">
    {{item.Scenario_id}}
    <div ng-repeat="subList in item.sub_list">
       {{subList.Scenario_sub.sub_result_id}}
    </div>
 </div>
```

here is the codepen for reference : [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/tvaibhav1204/pen/ZdzLQP)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not modify my json instead I modified my ng-repeat. It kind of works but the problem now is, since there are 2 scenario sub in the same sublist, only the 2nd scenario sub details are getting displayed. I s there any way to differentiate them or solve this issue ?

Comment: Yes, that's because, your JSON sublist looks liek this :[{ scenario1, scenario2 }] where as to run it in the ng-repeat it should be like [{scenario1},{scenario2}].

Comment: is there a way without altering my json

Comment: I really doubt that. there is no way that repeater can convert sub-objects --> array of objects. You will have to do the pre-processing of that array.